# Loading multiple layouts dynamically within one activity on android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout

I have an SQLite table on my application which has a set of questions. The activity where the user can take this test loads initially the first question, then every time they press next, it sets the text of the question and answers textView to the next row on the SQLite table.

The problem is, if I want the user to be able to click on the answer and move to the next question, then I want that answer to remain highlighted/checked if they press the previous question button - which means I think the best way would be to have all the questions loaded in separate layouts within the activity and for the activity to show one at a time.

Is it possible to loop through and create a layout each time or will that kill the memory?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do this for multiple reasons. It is rarely a good idea to have multiple `layouts` for one `Activity`. I don't know just how your `layout` is suppose to look but you can load `parent and child views` dynamically which is probably what you want to do if you don't know the number of questions each time.

You can create a `View` with something like

```
TextView question = new TextView(this);
```

then add it to a `layout` with `addView()`

You can have, say a `LinearLayout` in a separate file and [inflate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) that each time you need a new question and set the `Views` inside it accordingly.

Another option, if you know how many `Views` should be in your `layout` would be to create them in xml and use the `visibility` property `android:visibility="invisible"` in xml then change it to `visible` in Java when they click the `Button`

```
textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Its hard to give much of an example without knowing exactly what you have but I would suggest looking into one of these two options

One other option that you may consider if you have large `layout`s for each question/answer or want them to be reusable is to create the separate files for each and use the `<include>` tag to include each one in your main `layout`. You could also use the `visibility` property doing it this way and have separate files. You just want to try and avoid calling `setContentView()` multiple times because that will set all of your `Views` to their default values and it can get messy causing even more problems.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading all the layouts up front, you should store answers in sqlite as well, and set the values when that screen is loaded again. So the flow would go:

**onCreate** -> set content view

**onResume** -> check if an answer exists for the problem with an sqlite query. If an answer exists, set the value.

**onPause**  -> if answer is set, store to sqlite

Actually, you probably want to save when they click next button.. That will in turn call onPause though if you are then opening a new activity.